# Why locate GPS control/monitor segments near equator?

Tags: gps, satellite

It's well known why we launch satellites near the equator, but why are the GPS control/monitor segments located near the equator at Hawaii, Ecuador, Florida, Bahrain, Ascension, Diego Garcia, Guam and Kwajalein?

For example:

[image]

Comment: Which locations and/or precise legend items from your map are you considering to be "near the equator'?

Comment: Hawaii, Ecuador, Florida, Bahrain, Ascension, Diego Garcia, Guam, Kwajalein

Comment: Ground antennas on the equator are more likely to have a good angle to the satellites as they vary from ~55N to ~55S ground track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't seem to be 'near the equator'. Roughly georeferencing the locations of the stations and looking at the distribution of latitudes:

[image]

Data (very rough, but OK for these purposes):

```
wkt_geom    name    lon lat
Point (-152.0 61.0) Alaska  -152.0  61.0
Point (-61.6 76.4)  Greenland   -61.6   76.4
Point (-156.5 20.7) Hawaii  -156.5  20.7
Point (-121.3 35.9) Vandenburg  -121.3  35.9
Point (-103.3 37.3) Colorado    -103.3  37.3
Point (-76.1 40.3)  New Hampshire   -76.1   40.3
Point (-76.5 37.4)  Washington  -76.5   37.4
Point (-80.5 27.9)  Cape Canaveral  -80.5   27.9
Point (-78.1 1.4)   Ecuador -78.1   1.4
Point (-57.2 -34.8) Argentina   -57.2   -34.8
Point (-1.2 52.7)   UK  -1.2    52.7
Point (50.3 25.0)   Bahrain 50.3    25.0
Point (-10.4 -11.0) Ascension   -10.4   -11.0
Point (26.9 -27.9)  South Africa    26.9    -27.9
Point (127.7 35.4)  South Korea 127.7   35.4
Point (72.0 -7.2)   Diego Garcia    72.0    -7.2
Point (144.9 13.2)  Guam    144.9   13.2
Point (138.3 -33.9) Australia   138.3   -33.9
Point (172.9 -41.3) New Zealand 172.9   -41.3
```

Comment: I'd plot monitoring stations distinctly from ground antenna locations. Different functions, different geometry.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you're asking about the ground stations at Ascension, Diego Garcia and Kwajalein. 
The reason is pretty simple: they already housed US Air Force bases and complexes, as well as space launch tracking and ground infrastructure, and as the NAVSTAR system is operated by the [AFSPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Force_Space_Command), it's only logical to place the ground stations in a place controlled and maintained by the US Air Force.

I don't think there is any technical demands to place these station as close to the equator as possible, it's rather a matter of money and military control.